# How to correctly overload for generic collections

Tags: java, generics

UPDATE: please see comments, this was a red herring having to do with maven environment.

I searched for a similar question, but didn't find the same thing I am after.  I want to write a string utility class that assembles collections into a string, inserting a separator.

NOTE: PLEASE do not give me ways to assemble comma-separated Strings!  I know many ways to do that.  I want to understand the generic method mechanism.

For example:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("A");
strings.add("B");
strings.add("C");
StringUtils.assemble(strings, ","); ==> "A,B,C"
```

So I've written a generic method:

```
public static <T> String assemble(List<T> objs, String separator) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.size(); i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            sb.append(separator);
        }
        sb.append(objs.get(i).toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Unfortunately, calls to that method produce compilation errors:

```
class C1 { 
    public String toString() { ... }
}
class C2 {
    private List<C1> list;
    void foo() {
        StringUtils.assemble(list, ",");
    }
}

[ERROR] [...]/C2.java:[557,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method assemble(java.util.List<[...]C1>,java.lang.String)
  location: class [...]StringUtils
```

Is it possible to create a generic method that does what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Check that you're using `java.util.List` in your `StringUtils#assemble` method.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work.

Comment: Check your imports. Are you importing the right StringUtils class?

Comment: Hmmm, you all are right... extracting all of this into a standalone project works fine.

Comment: Well, weirdness.  I copied the project folders to a new location, and everything was fine.  Went back to original location, clean and build, everything is fine.  I really don't know what happened.  Can a local maven repo get stuck with bad versions of dependent projects?  Anyway, this question should be closed or ignored or something.  Or left as a warning to future travelers.